# error is preventing me from building an array of values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am receiving a parse error which is this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ... on line 91 which is this line:

```
$stmt->execute($parameters);
```

But what I want to know is what is causing this error from the code below and what do I need to change?

```
$parameters = array();

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery);      
    $parameters[] = ($each)   
    $stmt->execute($parameters);   
    $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionId,$dbQuestionContent,$dbOptionType,$dbNoofAnswers,$dbAnswer,$dbReplyType,$dbQuestionMarks); 
    $questionnum = $stmt->num_rows();
```

Comment: Missing a `;` after `$parameters[] = ($each)`.

Comment: When PHP reports an error on a line but you don't see an error there, always look to the line immediately preceding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a ; in the line before that.

```
 $parameters[] = ($each)
```

Should be

```
$parameters[] = ($each);
```